# How to disable emoticons in froala editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented the froala editor and created the froala id in dynamic because of need.This is working fine but I want to disable the emoticon in this editor.

```
$('#froala'+key).froalaEditor({


    imageUploadParam: 'image_upload',    
    imageUploadURL: EnvironmentConfig[env].DESCRIPTION_IMAGE_URL+'froala/setimage',
    imageUploadParams: {
       oemCode: oemCode
  },
   height:300
});
```

Can anyone suggest me the best way instead of removing the emoticon js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the defaults for the features available in the toolbar. Then just dont add the 'emoticons'.
Example:

```
$('#froalaEditor').froalaEditor({
   toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize']
});
```

An example with all the features can be found here:
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/full-featured